# Safari ClipboardEvent.clipboardData check if image pasted

Tags: javascript, html, safari

I need to add additional behavior when user paste image in mobile Safari. 
I use following code to get `clipboardData`:

```
document.getElementById('content').addEventListener('paste', function(e) {
    var clipboardData = e.clipboardData;
// check if image were pasted
}
```

From this point, how can I check is it image (jpg, png, gif) were pasted or not?

Answer (score 1):

I can't get data from `e.clipboardData` as it showed noting at all. so I use Editable div instead, then you can check if it is a image inside Editable div, and find what's in it.

```js
document.getElementById("content").addEventListener("paste", function(e) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    var pasted = $("#content").children();
    if (!pasted.length) {
      console.log("nothing pasted!");
      return;
    }
    pasted.map((i, x) => {
      if (x.tagName != "IMG") {
        console.log(x);
        console.log(`${x.tagName} not image`);
        return;
      }
      console.log(`pasted image=[${x.src}]!`);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#content {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='content' contenteditable='true'></div>
```

when you get `data-url` you can tel `jpg` or `png`, if not it will be more complicated, a back-end api is needed